# Error while burning bootloader

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, bootloader, avrdude

I am trying to burn bootloader on Arduino UNO using MEGA2560 as the programmer,
I followed the steps stated [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP) but still get the error below:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/arduino/arduino-nightly/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/webdev/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Error while burning bootloader.
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

**Note:** The Arduino UNO stopped responding when I mistakenly short-circuited a connection, I mistakenly passed 12v to one of the header pins of sensor shield mounted on the board.

**How it was connected**
[image: Connection diagram]

Comment: You note about short circuiting needs more explanation.  Depending on what you did the device may be damaged.

Comment: Clearly, however, the MEGA is not communicating with the Uno.  Please share how you have this hooked up.

Comment: @jwh20 I have included a connection diagram to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

> Note: The Arduino UNO stopped responding when I mistakenly
> short-circuited a connection, I mistakenly passed 12v to one of the
> header pins of sensor shield mounted on the board.

There are no I/O pins on the Arduino that are 12V tolerant.  You have almost certainly "fried" your Uno board.  It's possible the only casualty is the ATMega chip itself and replacements are available from a number of sources or you can purchase a "raw" one from an electronics reseller and use your programmer setup above to burn your own boot loader.

It's also quite likely that your sensor board is damaged as well.

From the Microchip datasheet:

[image]

You want something like this:

[Adafruit Pre-programmed ATMega168p](https://www.adafruit.com/product/123)

Buy several, accidents happen!

Comment: If it's any consolation, I've put 30VDC onto a pin of a Arduino Leonardo, just being sloppy with leads on a table.  Strangely, it "worked" after that, though not the GPIO pin. But, it was rather hot and bothered about it and so untrustworthy thereafter; I mean it ran code, but you could fry an egg on it while it was doing so.  I replaced the chip on it and now it's fine.  **It is entirely possible that only the AVR on your UNO is dead and with some work may be replaced.**  If it's a DIP based UNO as pictured, this is comparatively easy.

Comment: Anyone who has experimented with electronics for any length of time has experience "smoke".  I've lost track of how many expensive chips I've fried due to one oversight or another.

Comment: Or an Adafruit Pre-programmed ATMega**328**P rather.